# Authentication time-out Sliding expiration in .net application not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, webforms

I have the following configuration in my web.config.

```
<authentication mode="None">
            <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

I was testing authentication time out in my web application. I have logged in to my application `at 2:00:00 sec`  and after `1 min 30 sec (at 2:01:30sec)` i accessed the application again(ideally now the authentication cookie should reset ). And `at 2:02:03 sec` i accessed the application and this time `time-out` has happened. I don't know why authentication cookie is not resetting.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks...

Comment: What does the cookie say for Expires when you inspect it?

Comment: The mode attribute of your authentication element is set to "None"? Should the value not be "Forms" instead?